# Difference between 的 and 个

Tags: meaning, difference, cantonese

Does it make sense to say 我个心? I suppose its meant to be 我的心. I still cannot distinguish when to use it. Maybe it to do with the fact that I am a Cantonese speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It totally make sense to *say* 我个心 colloquially in spoken Cantonese.
我的心 is used in Mandarian or formal written Chinese.

Moreover, 个 in 我个心 is not really used as a quantifier in 我个心
个 in 我有一个心 can be used as a quantifier, but it's not a common usage, every one has one heart.

个 in 我个心 here, is the same as 's in "I's" or My in English
so both *我个* 心(Cantonese) or *我的* 心(written/Mandarin) mean *my* heart

Answer (score 2):

我个心 does not make sense. I guess you're confusing 个 with 嘅.

我**嘅**广东话讲得好唔好 => 我**的**广东话说得好不好

—————————————————————————

**个(quantifier) pattern：number + 个 + noun**

examples：一个人，六个核桃

when used without a number it normally just mean one：

我有个朋友 => 我有**一**个朋友

—————————————————————————

**的(particle) pattern：noun/pronoun + 的 + noun**

examples: 我的心，我喜欢的人，聪明的孩子

Comment: 我個心 is used in Cantonese... How does it not make sense?

Answer (score 2):

个 is the simplified version of the traditional character 個.

個 is a classifier for many objects including 心 in Cantonese.  '

Example: 你個頭，佢個胃，我個肺 (your head, his brain, my lungs)

The Cantonese phrase 呢**個**心 (this heart) in Mandarin would be 這**顆**心

The Cantonese phrase 我(呢)**個**心 (this heart of mine) in Mandarin would be 我這**顆**心

The Mandarin 我**的**心 in Cantonese would be 我**嘅**心